# jQuery Json filter with search input without using any filter plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter

I am able to show `Json` data in `html` view, but how can I now `filter` json data list based on `firstname` as I type in `search` input box, please help me I am new to `javascript` & `jQuery`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" value="" />
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
var data={"users":[
        {
            "firstName":"Ray",
            "lastName":"Villalobos",
            "joined": {
                "month":"January",
                "day":12,
                "year":2012
            }
        },
        {
            "firstName":"John",
            "lastName":"Jones",
            "joined": {
                "month":"April",
                "day":28,
                "year":2010
            }
        }
]}

$(data.users).each(function() {
    var output = "<ul><li>" + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "--" + this.joined.month+"</li></ul>";
    $('#placeholder').append(output);
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcpGN/9651/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use following

```js
var data = {
    "users": [{
        "firstName": "Ray",
            "lastName": "Villalobos",
            "joined": {
            "month": "January",
                "day": 12,
                "year": 2012
        }
    }, {
        "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Jones",
            "joined": {
            "month": "April",
                "day": 28,
                "year": 2010
        }
    }]
}

$(data.users).each(function () {
    var output = "<ul><li>" + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "--" + this.joined.month + "</li></ul>";
    $('#placeholder').append(output);
});
$('#search').change(function () {
    var yourtext = $(this).val();
    if (yourtext.length > 0) {
        $("li:contains(" + yourtext + ")").addClass('notify');
    }
    else{
        $("li:contains(" + yourtext + ")").removeClass('notify');
    }
});
```

```css
.notify{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" value="" />
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

**Up Dated**

```js
var data = {
    "users": [{
        "firstName": "Ray",
            "lastName": "Villalobos",
            "joined": {
            "month": "January",
                "day": 12,
                "year": 2012
        }
    }, {
        "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Jones",
            "joined": {
            "month": "April",
                "day": 28,
                "year": 2010
        }
    }]
}

$(data.users).each(function () {
    var output = "<ul><li>" + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "--" + this.joined.month + "</li></ul>";
    $('#placeholder').append(output);
});
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var yourtext = $(this).val();
    if (yourtext.length > 0) {
        $("li:not(:contains(" + yourtext + "))").hide();
    }
    else{
        
        $("li").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" value="" />
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

**Up Dated 2**

```js
var data = {
    "users": [{
        "firstName": "Ray",
            "lastName": "Villalobos",
            "joined": {
            "month": "January",
                "day": 12,
                "year": 2012
        }
    }, {
        "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Jones",
            "joined": {
            "month": "April",
                "day": 28,
                "year": 2010
        }
    }]
}

$(data.users).each(function () {
    var output = "<ul><li>" + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "--" + this.joined.month + "</li></ul>";
    $('#placeholder').append(output);
});
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var yourtext = $(this).val();
    if (yourtext.length > 0) {
        var abc = $("li").filter(function () {
            var str = $(this).text();
            var re = new RegExp(yourtext, "i");
            var result = re.test(str);
            if (!result) {
                return $(this);
            }
        }).hide();
    } else {
        $("li").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" value="" />
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but can you please update it like, how auto suggestions work when we type in search box it's shows filtered list based on search value.

Comment: but why input is require case sensitive like when I type "ray" it not shows list but when I type "Ray" then it shows 1st list.

Comment: I think `contains selector` is `case sensitive`

Comment: so any possibility is there to remove case sensitive behavior.

Comment: @Amit find Up Dated 2 version.

Comment: Thanks for the help &  you have great knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

use [$.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

**See this example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/ejPV4/317/

```
var data={"users":[
        {
            "firstName":"Ray",
            "lastName":"Villalobos",
            "joined": {
                "month":"January",
                "day":12,
                "year":2012
            }
        },
        {
            "firstName":"John",
            "lastName":"Jones",
            "joined": {
                "month":"April",
                "day":28,
                "year":2010
            }
        }
]}

var found_names = $.grep(data.users, function(v) {
    return v.firstName === "John" ;
});

console.log(found_names);
```

---

**Edit**

see this fiddle with key press event.

http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/ejPV4/320/

Comment: but here you are using search button, is it possible to filter data without search button like on `key-type` or `keyup` only.

Comment: if you clear text then you will get old data and in keypress it will find data

Comment: yeah that I can see now, but is it not possible to show data list if I type only "r" or "R" or "ra" like that for 1st data list.

Comment: @amit i think you can use select2 in your project it wil automatically do filtering and searching many more features